# How many (linear) order types are there on a set of n elements?

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

Given number $n$ variables $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$. How many way can we place $>$, $=$ between them ?

For example, for $n = 3$ (Let's call $a_1 = x, a_2=y, a_3=z$ for convenient). There are 13 way:
 $$x = y = z;\ x = y > z;\ x > y = z;\ x > y > z;\ x > z > y;\ x = z > y;\
y > x = z;\ y > x > z;\ y > z > x;\ y = z > x;\ z > x = y;\ z > x > y;\  z > y > x.$$

For $n$ small enough, I can count it by brute-force, but what about for a large $n$. Is there a formula ? How can I get it ?

Thank you.

Comment: So $x = y > z$ and $y = x > z$ are considered to be the same? If so would be better to define the problem sematically? Like “How many (linear) order types are there on a set of $n$ elements”?

Comment: Sorry, I am not good at English;
edited as your suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of ways $n$ objects can be weakly ordered is the $n$-th [Ordered Bell Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number) or $n$-th Fubini-number  $a(n)$.

These can be calculated using the [Stirling numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) of the first kind: $S(n,k)$ is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ elements in $k$ disjoint subsets. So if we sum over the number of $=$-groups in the ordering, there are $S(n,k)$ ways to partition the $n$ element into groups such that all elements in one group are equal, and $k!$ ways to order these groups by $>$-signs. Thus

$$a(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n k! S(n,k)$$
By using formulas for the Stirling numbers we get another unexpected identity: $$a(n) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{m^n}{2^{m}}$$

Comment: Also check http://oeis.org/A000670 and wikipedia for other formulas including generating functions and recurrence relations.