# Number of ordered set partitions

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I have encountered a counting problem which involves counting all ordered partitions.

I give an example: Given a set of two elements $\{A,B\}$, there are two partitions, $\{\{A,B\}\}$ and $\{\{A\},\{B\}\}$, but there are three ordered partitions, $(\{A,B\})$, $(\{A\},\{B\})$, and $(\{B\},\{A\})$.

I have to count them for a set of order $2^N$ with $N$ growing.

I am aware of the Stirling number $k\brace r$ of the second kind, which describes the number of $k$-partitions of a set with cardinality $r$.

So I get some thing like this
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{2^n} k!{{2^n}\brace k} $$

Are there closed formulas for this problem? Is this problem wellstudied in combinatorics? Are asymptotic formulas known?

I am happy for any advice or reference I can get.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but I had a think about this last night... If you take the set of all elements of all partitions of the cardinality of your set, the closed form is the sum of the factorials of all those elements.  So suppose you begin with a set of cardinality 3: 3 can be partitioned into {1,1,1}, {1,2}, {2,1}. So your result is $5\times1!+2\times2!$. That looks trivially equivalent to Brian's answer below.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625703/how-many-linear-order-types-are-there-on-a-set-of-n-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the [ordered Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number) (or Fubini numbers)

$$a(n)=\sum_{k=0}^nk!{n\brace k}\;;$$

asymptotically they satisfy

$$a(n)\approx\frac{n!}{2(\ln 2)^{n+1}}\;.$$

The sequence of these numbers is [OEIS A000670](https://oeis.org/A000670), where you’ll find many references and much information; there don’t seem to be any nice closed forms. You’re interested specifically in $a(n)$ when $n$ is a power of $2$; it does not appear to me that this helps.

Comment: Isn't it weird that that number is smaller than $n!$, but if we restrict ourselves to the case of partitions of type (1, 1, .., 1) we end up with $n!$ ordered partitions?